# How to help my 7-year-old son socialize in school and learn to fight for his rights?

Tags: primary-schooler, relationships, social-development, friends

My son is 7 years old. He's very polite, shy, sensitive and honest. Unlike other kids in his class who tend to be more selfish and mean. I wonder why don't they like to play with him. Although he's very polite and caring.

Today we were invited to a birthday party and I saw how other kids wanted to sit next to each other but not next to him and how they preferred to play with each other. He's a bit quiet and tends to have a quiet personality. And as he's my only child, he doesn't know how to fight for his rights and take his turn. It breaks my heart to see him like this.

What can I do to make him stronger and what can I do to let other kids in his class love to play with him?

Comment: Hi Dorothydo. You might want to edit your question so it clearly a single question whose answers can be evaluated objectively, in keeping with the q&a format of SE. I've taken a swing at answering it as "what can I do to help my son become more assertive in socializing".

Answer (score 3):

I have recently started taking my son (just 8) to a gaming club. We started out playing Pokemon cards, and he is starting to branch out into other tabletop games. Players of all ages interact freely and supportively.

Tabletop games don't work unless everyone participates, so he's guaranteed a turn. As he gets more into it, he will become more assertive, and that may carry over into the rest of life (at the least he will have a place he can hang with friends he can interact with). Check out your local game stores/game lounges.

Answer (score 0):

The other kids won't change, unfortunately you need to help your kid start to have a more "competitive" personality. Enroll him in something interesting, where he can feel comfortable interacting with other kids. It can be a sport or something he likes to do.